# Ros turtlebot navigation

Tags: ros, navigation, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi everyone
im new in ubuntu and currently learning to understand ROS. im working on a project which required ROS to program turtbot for navigation.
the problem is I dont know where and what to start. im just following the ROS tutorial provided. can anyone enlighten me on how and what should i do first.what is the step from creating workspace to programming turtlebot.

im so lost here :(

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190716/ros-turtlebot-navigation/) by [lfyhmdn](https://answers.ros.org/users/20052/lfyhmdn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2014-08-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I understand your situation and I've been in this situation when I started learning ROS. It's really hard to give you an answer to your question, but I can make suggestions:

- For instance, make sure your understand the basics and fundamentals of ROS before start concerning how to program your turtlebot.
- Go through the ROS tutorials and make sure to understand what are the meanings of nodes, topics, messages, launch files, listeners, and publishers. Just try to get the big picture!
- Try to understand how to configure your CMakeLists.txt and your package.xml
- User Eclipse or QTCreator as an IDE for your project, instead of using a text editor for writing your code)
- Divide your project into many stages (start with the easier stages and move on to the the more difficult as your ROS skills improve)
- Whenever you face a problem, do not hesitate to ask questions on ROS Answers. So many ppl will be glad to help (as long as you show them you tried and put efforts to solve the problem).

If you find any of the points vague, let me know and I will explain more. Don't give up! ROS seems to be impossible at the beginning, but once you get used to it you will find it cool! It just takes time (as it's the case with every open-source library/software)

Good luck...

---

Originally posted by [emacsd](https://answers.ros.org/users/3662/emacsd/) with karma: 194 on 2014-08-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2